# C# Always 0 Arguments

Tags: c#, winforms, arguments, associations

I have associated my program with this method :

```
public static void CreateFileAssociation(string extension, string key, string description, string path)
{
    RegistryKey classes = Registry.ClassesRoot;
    RegistryKey extensionKey = classes.CreateSubKey(extension);
    extensionKey.SetValue(null, key);

    RegistryKey typeKey = classes.CreateSubKey(key);
    typeKey.SetValue(null, description);

    RegistryKey shellKey = typeKey.CreateSubKey("shell");
    RegistryKey shellOpenKey = shellKey.CreateSubKey("open");
    RegistryKey shellOpenCommandKey = shellOpenKey.CreateSubKey("command");
    shellOpenCommandKey.SetValue(null, path);
}
```

My `Program.cs` :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1(args.TryGet(0)));
}
```

And my `Form1.cs` :

```
string filenameArg = "";

public Form1(string arg)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    filenameArg = arg;
}
```

When i open my associated file(extension), My program starts with no arguments

Don't know what's the problem with this. What's wrong with it ?

Comment: You forgot to show us the most important part: what's inside `path` when you write it to registry?

Comment: My application is External , means that can run from anywhere so i copy it in appdata\local\myProgram  always in startup

so path is : ...appdata\local\myProgram\prog.exe

Comment: You show in program.cs string[] args;  args.TryGet(0);  string[] contains no defintion TryGet method on string[]?  I am checking this with c# 6.0

Comment: @DaveS TryGet is my extension method that tries to get value from an index , a safe method :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably missed the `%1` in your command value:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\...\shell\open\command = ...appdata\local\myProgram\prog.exe "%1"
```

The `%1` is replaced by the path of the file you selected. Put it in double quotes so that paths with white spaces get passed as a single argument, too.